# Capture IP Address

Tags: php

I am using the following processor to send **name, email and phone** to a flatfile.

```
<?php
$vname = $_GET["visitor"];
$vemail = $_GET["visitormail"];
$vphone = $_GET["visitorphone"];
print("<b>Thank You!</b><br />Your information will be entered once into the raffle!");
$out = fopen("savedinfo.php", "a");
if (!$out) {
print("Could not append to file");
exit;
}
fputs ($out, "\n");
fwrite($out,"$vname, $vemail, $vphone.");
fclose($out);
?>
```

I have tried various means to likewise send the **ip** address to the flatfile but cannot get to work!

I start with this line `<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ipi ?>" />`

and seek to achieve a result as follows  `fwrite($out,"$vname, $vemail, $vphone, $ipi.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`. This is standard PHP.

You can view a list of all available `$_SERVER` values here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a variable named `$ip`, you'll have to set it first:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
fwrite($out,"$vname, $vemail, $vphone, $ip.");
```